# Formatting: two block-quotes in a row?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If I want to give a quotation, I can set it out as a block-quote and it looks beautiful:

> My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings; / Look on my works, ye mighty, and despair!

But if I want two such quotations in a row, I don’t know how to separate them.  I’ve tried several options, and none works: just separating them by an empty line

```
  > Ask not what your country can do for you — ask what you can do for your country.

  > And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; It tolls for thee.
```

merges to a single block-quote (even if more separating lines are added):

> Ask not what your country can do for you — ask what you can do for your country.
>
> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; It tolls for thee.

Adding a non-breaking space on the separating line merges even more:

```
  > In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.
  [non-breaking space here] 
  > Call me Ishmael.
```

makes it a single line:

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.
>    
>   Call me Ishmael.

Adding an empty line after the non-breaking space makes it identical to the first example.  Adding an empty line *before* the non-breaking space

```
  > Oh Romeo, Romeo, wherefore are thou Romeo?

  [non-breaking space here]
  > To be or not to be, that is the question.
```

looks perfect in the preview, but leaves a full blank line in the final rendering — much too large a gap:

> Oh Romeo, Romeo, wherefore are thou Romeo?

> To be or not to be, that is the question.

Is there a better option than any of these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Ask not what your country can do for you — ask what you can do for your country.

> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; It tolls for thee.

```
> Ask not what your country can do for you — ask what you can do for your country.    

<!-- hey there sailor -->    

> And therefore never send to know for whom the bell tolls; It tolls for thee.
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks muchly for an effective and authoritative answer.